Acomodar archivos por extension y por identificador en python
Necesito organizar los archivos que descargo en mi directorio "Descargas". Hice un script en Python, pero necesito que organice los archivos por carpeta, pero la carpeta necesita el nombre del archivo sin la extensión y si el archivo tiene un nombre diferente, cada uno que se organiza en una carpeta diferente. Mi código está a continuación:
import os
import shutil
# Directorio de origen y destino
directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/DZMD6S0/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección donde quieres introducir tus archivos:\n')

# Comprobar si el directorio de destino existe, si no, crearlo
if not os.path.exists(directorio_destino):
    os.makedirs(directorio_destino)

# Obtener la lista de archivos en el directorio de origen
archivos = os.listdir(directorio_origen)

# Buscar un archivo con la extensión .inc o .pc para usar su nombre como nombre de carpeta
nombre_carpeta = None
for archivo in archivos:
    if archivo.endswith('.inc') or archivo.endswith('.pc'):
        nombre_carpeta = os.path.splitext(archivo)[0]
        break

if nombre_carpeta is None:
    print("No se encontraron archivos con las extensiones .inc o .pc en el directorio de origen.")
    exit()

# Crear la ruta completa del directorio de destino
ruta_carpeta_destino = os.path.join(directorio_destino, nombre_carpeta)
# Comprobar si la carpeta de destino ya existe, si no, crearla
if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta_destino):
    os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta_destino)

# Iterar sobre cada archivo
for archivo in archivos:
    # Obtener la extensión del archivo
    nombre, extension = os.path.splitext(archivo)
    # Verificar si la extensión es .inc o .pc
    if extension in ['.inc', '.pc']:
        # Construir la ruta completa del archivo de origen y destino
        ruta_origen = os.path.join(directorio_origen, archivo)
        ruta_destino = os.path.join(ruta_carpeta_destino, archivo)
        # Copiar el archivo al directorio de destino
        shutil.copy2(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)
        print(f"Archivo {archivo} copiado correctamente a {ruta_carpeta_destino}")

#Ejemplo de nombres

XA40.inc
XA40.pc
AA20.inc
AA20.pc

Por lógica necesito que cada XA40 se acomoden en una carpeta con puros XA40
Asi como los AA20 todos en una misma carpeta donde contenga todos los AA20
Espero me puedan ayudar
Saludos

Por favor, edita la pregunta y coloca correctamente el código entre las triple comillas invertidas (```) que le puse al principio y final del mismo. No se entiende dónde van las indentaciones, Por ejemplo, el 3er if que aparece, no se sabe si va dentro del for o fuera.

Listo @aeportugal

El problema que tienes es que ruta_carpeta_destino es siempre un valor fijo, en este caso es el primer nombre que cumpla con la condición. Por lo tanto en el último for, todos los archivos van a ser copiados a esa ruta.
Lo que tiene que hacer el script es comportarse dinámicamente archivo por archivo y copiarlo a la ruta correspondiente. Con makedirs() siempre intentará crear el directorio; pero con la bandera exists_ok=True verificará si ya existe y en ese caso no hará nada.
import os, shutil

directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/DZMD6S0/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección para tus archivos...')

for f in os.listdir(directorio_origen):
    fname, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if fext in ['.inc', '.pc']:
        pathdst = os.path.join(directorio_destino, fname)
        os.makedirs(pathdst, exist_ok=True)
        src = os.path.join(directorio_origen, f)
        dst = os.path.join(pathdst, f)
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)
        print(f"Archivo {f} copiado correctamente a {pathdst}")

Para acomodar los archivos en directorios nombrados por su extensión, cambiar a esta linea:
pathdst = os.path.join(directorio_destino, fext[1:])

Hola @aeportugal que tal muchas gracias por ser parte de la solucion, pero existe alguna forma de que se almacenen en una sola carpeta cada uno? por ejemplo. Si mis archivos son XX01.inc, XX01.pc y tengo otros que son ZZ01.inc y ZZ01.pc. Que los XX01 se guarden en una sola carpeta de acuerdo a esa parte del nombre y todos los ZZ01 en otra.
Es posible hacer eso?
